# Iterate variable for every node | Node Connectivity in Python Graph

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I would like to find node connectivity between node 1 and rest of the nodes in a graph. The input text file format is as follows:

```
1 2 1
1 35 1
8 37 1
```

and so on for 167 lines. First column represents source node, second column represents destination node while the last column represents weight of the edge.

I'm trying to read the source, destination nodes from input file and forming an edge between them. I need to then find out if it is a connected network (only one component of graph and no sub-components). Here is the code

```
from numpy import*
import networkx as nx
G=nx.empty_graph()

for row in file('out40.txt'):
    row = row.split()
    src = row[0]
    dest = row[1]
    #print src
    G.add_edge(src, dest)
    print src, dest

for i in range(2, 41):
    if nx.bidirectional_dijkstra(G, 1, i): print "path exists from 1 to ", i
```

manually adding the edges using

```
G.add_edge(1, 2)
```

works but is tedious and not suitable for large input files such as mine. The if loop condition works when I add edges manually but throws the following error for the above code:

```
in neighbors_iter
raise NetworkXError("The node %s is not in the graph."%(n,))
networkx.exception.NetworkXError: The node 2 is not in the graph.
```

Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, you're adding nodes `"1"` and `"2"` et cetera (since reading from a file is going to give you strings unless you explicitly convert them).

However, you're then trying to refer to nodes `1` and `2`. I'm guessing that `networkx` does not think that `2 == "2"`.

Try changing this...

```
G.add_edge(src, dest)
```

to this:

```
G.add_edge(int(src), int(dest))
```

Comment: @bhanu: If this is the right solution for you, please mark it as such (and vote the useful answers up)

Comment: @Rabarberski I did that! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if that is an option for you, but are you aware of the **build-in support of networkx for multiple graph text formats**?

The [edge list format](http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/readwrite.edgelist.html) seems to apply pretty well to your case. Specifically, the following method will read your input files without the need for custom code:

```
G = nx.read_weighted_edgelist(filename)
```

If you want to remove the weights (because you don't need them), you could subsequently do the following:

```
for e in G.edges_iter(data=True):
    e[2].clear()                   #[2] is the 3rd element of the tuple, which 
                                   #contains the dictionary with edge attributes
```

Comment: Thank you, I haven't looked in to it. I will explore this.

Comment: I've edited my answer, the `read_weighted_edgelist()` method is exactly what you need I think.

Comment: Great! I think I will use this in future when I work with weighted edges. Currently, working with un-weighted edges. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

From `Networkx` [documentation](http://networkx.lanl.gov/tutorial/tutorial.html):

```
for row in file('out40.txt'):
    row = row.split()
    src = row[0]
    dest = row[1]
    G.add_nodes_from([src, dest])
    #print src
    G.add_edge(src, dest)
    print src, dest
```

The error message says the the graph `G` doesn't have the nodes you are looking to create an edge in between.

Comment: Amber answered it! I did not typecast it to integer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use "is_connected()" to make this a little simpler. e.g.

```
$ cat disconnected.edgelist
1 2 1
2 3 1
4 5 1
$ cat connected.edgelist 
1 2 1
2 3 1
3 4 1
$ ipython

In [1]: import networkx as nx

In [2]: print(nx.is_connected(nx.read_weighted_edgelist('disconnected.edgelist')))
False

In [3]: print(nx.is_connected(nx.read_weighted_edgelist('connected.edgelist')))
True
```

Comment: Thanks @aric, I'm using 'nx.number_connected_components(G)' to find if a graph is connected or not. However, I would like to know if there is a way to join two disconnected components of a graph. Are you aware of any approach? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to load the file as a pandas dataframe and then use `iterrows` to iterate:

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx

cols = ["src", "des", "wei"]
df = pd.read_csv('out40.txt', sep=" ", header=None, names=cols)
G = nx.empty_graph()

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    G.add_edge(row["src"], row["des"])
```